# PHP - Diferencia de fecha y tiempo según zonas horarias

Tags: php

Tengo un pequeño sistema de usuarios, donde los usuarios realizan reportes que se almacenan en la base de datos.

Los usuarios son los siguientes:

1. **`ID: 1, Nombre: Carlos, DatoUsuario: 05/04/2017 11:06am, ZonaHoraria: NL - Paises Bajos.`**
2. **`ID: 2, Nombre: Andres, DatoUsuario: 05/04/2017 4:10am, ZonaHoraria: CO - Colombia.`**

Ahora bien, **segun la zona horaria se guarda la fecha y la hora para la publicacion de reportes de los usuarios**:

1. **`Reporte: 2, Informacion: Lorem ipsum, Dato: 05/04/2017 2:00pm.`**
2. **`Reporte: 5, Informacion: Lorem ipsum, Dato: 05/04/2017 7:15am.`**

Ahora, la diferencia en horas que hay entre Colombia y Paises Bajos es de 7 (Segun tiempo).

Teniendo como Zona Horaria Principal "America/Bogota"

Como puedo hacer que la diferencia en tiempo (Publicado hace ... tiempo) resulte de 15 minutos y no de 7 horas y 15 minutos?

Comment: ¿Cómo guardas esa información en la base de datos? Por favor, agrega más información ya que no sé a primera vista dónde estás haciendo mal la conversión de fechas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la base de datos, almacena las fechas siempre en UTC (`date('c')`) y la zona horaria en otro campo. Puede que necesites ejecutar esto primero: `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`.

Una vez ya tengas todas las fechas en UTC, es fácil hacer cálculos con ellas.

Por ejemplo, si quieres mostrar la diferencia entre dos reports, calculas `$fecha_reporte1 - $fecha_reporte2` (utiliza para ello `DateTime::diff()`) y ni siquiera tienes que mirar en qué zona horaria está cada uno.

O si quieres mostrar la antigüedad de un reporte, utilizas `time() - $fecha_reporte`.

Tendrás que convertir a una zona horaria específica cuando quieras mostrar exactamente cuándo se creó el reporte. Ahí puedes elegir entre la zona horaria del servidor, la de la configuración del usuario o la del browser.